# Read in text file - 1 character at a time. using C

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

I'm trying to read in a text file line by line and process each character individually.

For example, one line in my text file might look like this:
`ABC XXXX XXXXXXXX ABC`

There will always be a different amount of spaces in the line. But the same number of characters (including spaces).

This is what I have so far...

```
char currentLine[100];
fgets(currentLine, 22, inputFile);
```

I'm then trying to iterate through the currentLine Array and work with each character...

```
for (j = 0; j<22; j++) {
    if (&currentLine[j] == 'x') {
        // character is an x... do something
     }
}
```

Can anyone help me with how I should be doing this?

As you can probably tell - I've just started using C.

Comment: `fgets` will always read n - 1 bytes, or until the first carriage return, and then nul-terminate the buffer, so you only need `currentline` to be 22 bytes (if each line is no more than 21 characters).

Comment: @Martin: what about the carriage return itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the following is the canonical way to process a file character by character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file.txt\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt"))) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

        // now do something with each character, c.

    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `c` is declared `int`, not `char` because `EOF` has a value that is distinct from all characters that can be stored in a `char`.

For more complex parsing, then reading the file a line at a time is generally the right approach. You will, however, want to be much more defensive against input data that is not formatted correctly. Essentially, write the code to assume that the outside world is hostile. Never assume that the file is intact, even if it is a file that you just wrote.

For example, you are using a 100 character buffer to read lines, but limiting the amount read to 22 characters (probably because you know that 22 is the "correct" line length). The extra buffer space is fine, but you should allow for the possibility that the file might contain a line that is the wrong length. Even if that is an error, you have to decide how to handle that error and either resynchronize your process or abandon it.

**Edit:** I've added some skeleton of an assumed rest of the program for the canonical simple case. There are couple of things to point out there for new users of C. First, I've assumed a simple command line interface to get the name of the file to process, and verified using `argc` that an argument is really present. If not, I print a brief usage message taking advantage of the content of `argv[0]` which by convention names the current program in some useful way, and exit with a non-zero status.

I open the file for reading in text mode. The distinction between text and binary modes is unimportant on Unix platforms, but can be important on others, especially Windows. Since the discussion is of processing the file a character at a time, I'm assuming that the file is text and not binary. If `fopen()` fails, then it returns NULL and sets the global variable `errno` to a descriptive code for why it failed. The call to `perror()` translates `errno` to something human-readable and prints it along with a provided string. Here I've provided the name of the file we attempted to open. The result will look something like "foo.txt: no such file". We also exit with non-zero status in this case. I haven't bothered, but it is often sensible to exit with distinct non-zero status codes for distinct reasons, which can help shell scripts make better sense of errors.

Finally, I close the file. In principle, I should also test the `fclose()` for failure. For a process that just reads a file, most error conditions will already have been detected as some kind of content error, and there will be no useful status added at the close. For file writing, however, you might not discover certain I/O errors until the call to `fclose()`. When writing a file it is good practice to check return codes and expect to handle I/O errors at *any* call that touches the file.

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple with `fgetc`. It's unlikely a beginner wants/needs to work with arrays and pointers for reading a line at a time when the question was specifically about character-at-a-time processing.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the address operator (&).  You're trying to compare the value of the variable currentLine[j] to 'x', not it's address.

Answer (score 1):

`ABC XXXX XXXXXXXX ABC` has 21 characters. There's also the line break (22 chars) and the terminating null byte (23 chars).

You need to `fgets(currentLine, 23, inputFile);` to read the full line.

But you declared currentLine as an array of 100. Why not use all of it?

```
fgets(currentLine, sizeof currentLine, inputFile);
```

When using all of it, it doesn't mean that the system will put more than a line each time `fgets` is called. `fgets` always stops after reading a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while( fgets(currentLine, 100, inputFile) ) {
    for (j = 0; j<22; j++) {
        if (/*&*/currentLine[j] == 'x') { /* <--- without & */
        // character is an x... do something
        }
    }
}
```